# Vue.js seems to ignore inline-template directive?

Tags: vuejs2

I'm having trouble getting vue.js 2 to recognise an inline-template directive with a component.

There is a wrapping div inside the component tags; and tried it with or without a default template in the component definition.

This has worked for other components (and works for this component with a different html) but, for some reason, fails to work in this use case.

I've checked the html and it seems to be valid.

However, when I add @click to the controls (eg. @click="prev()") I get an "Invalid Character" error. And if I add {{ offset }} into the html it doesn't get replaced. I'm assuming this is because it's using the default template/slot definition.

As far as I can see it's just not recognising the inline-template attribute.

Any suggestions as to what I might be missing would be appreciated, thank you.

vue.js snippet:

```
    'slider': {
        computed: {
            animatedOffset: function() {
              return this.targetOffset.toFixed(0);
            }
        },
        watch: {
            offset: function(newValue) {
              TweenLite.to(this.$data, 0.5, { targetOffset: newValue });
            }
        },
        data: function() {
            return {
                offset: 0,
                targetOffset: 0,
                container: null,
                maxWidth: null, 
                width: null
            };
        },
        methods: {
            prev: function() {
                if (this.offset < 0) {
                    this.offset += this.width;
                } else {
                    this.offset = this.width - this.maxWidth;
                }
            },
            next: function() {
                this.offset -= this.width;
                if (this.offset <= -this.maxWidth) {
                    this.offset = 0;
                }
            }
        },
        mounted: function () {
            if (this.$refs.container) {
                this.container = this.$refs.container;
            } else {
                this.container = this.$el;
            }

            this.offset = 0;
            this.width = this.container.offsetWidth;
            this.maxWidth = !this.container.children ? this.width : this.width * this.container.children.length;
        },
        template: `
            <div class="slider">
                <slot></slot>
            </div>
        `
    }
```

html snippet:

```
<slider inline-template>
<div>
    <div class="timetable__table  row">
        <div class="timetable__label col-sm-3 col-6 p2 p3-sm h3-xs">
            <span>St Mawes Quay</span>
        </div>
        <div class="timetable__wrapper col-sm-9 col-6" ref="container" :style="{ left: animatedOffset+'px' }">
            <div class="timetable__times">
                <p class="timetable__cell p3 bg-zebra-xs">
                    -
                </p>
                <p class="timetable__cell p3 bg-zebra bg-zebra-xs">
                    0945*
                </p>
                <p class="timetable__cell p3 bg-zebra-xs">
                    1135
                </p>
                <p class="timetable__cell p3 bg-zebra">
                    1245
                </p>
                <p class="timetable__cell p3">
                    -
                </p>
                <p class="timetable__cell p3 bg-zebra">
                    -
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="timetable__table  row">
        <div class="timetable__label col-sm-3 col-6 p2 p3-sm h3-xs">
            <span class="fg-inherit">FALMOUTH PW Pier</span>
        </div>
        <div class="timetable__wrapper col-sm-9 col-6" ref="container" :style="{ left: animatedOffset+'px' }">
            <div class="timetable__times">
                <p class="timetable__cell p3 bg-zebra-xs">
                    0900
                </p>
                <p class="timetable__cell p3 bg-zebra bg-zebra-xs">
                    1030
                </p>
                <p class="timetable__cell p3 bg-zebra-xs">
                    1215
                </p>
                <p class="timetable__cell p3 bg-zebra">
                    1315
                </p>
                <p class="timetable__cell p3">
                    1515
                </p>
                <p class="timetable__cell p3 bg-zebra">
                    1615
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="timetable__table  row">
        <div class="timetable__label col-sm-3 col-6 p2 p3-sm h3-xs">
            <span>St Mawes Quay</span>
        </div>
        <div class="timetable__wrapper col-sm-9 col-6" ref="container" :style="{ left: animatedOffset+'px' }">
            <div class="timetable__times">
                <p class="timetable__cell p3 bg-zebra-xs">
                    <i class="glyphicons glyphicons-circle-arrow-down"></i>
                </p>
                <p class="timetable__cell p3 bg-zebra bg-zebra-xs">
                    <i class="glyphicons glyphicons-circle-arrow-down"></i>
                </p>
                <p class="timetable__cell p3 bg-zebra-xs">
                    <i class="glyphicons glyphicons-circle-arrow-down"></i>
                </p>
                <p class="timetable__cell p3 bg-zebra">
                    <i class="glyphicons glyphicons-circle-arrow-down"></i>
                </p>
                <p class="timetable__cell p3">
                    1535
                </p>
                <p class="timetable__cell p3 bg-zebra">
                    <i class="glyphicons glyphicons-circle-arrow-down"></i>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="timetable__table  row">
        <div class="timetable__label col-sm-3 col-6 p2 p3-sm h3-xs">
            <span>Trelissick Garden</span>
        </div>
        <div class="timetable__wrapper col-sm-9 col-6" ref="container" :style="{ left: animatedOffset+'px' }">
            <div class="timetable__times">
                <p class="timetable__cell p3 bg-zebra-xs">
                    0930
                </p>
                <p class="timetable__cell p3 bg-zebra bg-zebra-xs">
                    1110
                </p>
                <p class="timetable__cell p3 bg-zebra-xs">
                    1255
                </p>
                <p class="timetable__cell p3 bg-zebra">
                    1355
                </p>
                <p class="timetable__cell p3">
                    1610
                </p>
                <p class="timetable__cell p3 bg-zebra">
                    1655
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="timetable__table  row">
        <div class="timetable__label col-sm-3 col-6 p2 p3-sm h3-xs">
            <span>TRURO Town Quay</span>
        </div>
        <div class="timetable__wrapper col-sm-9 col-6" ref="container" :style="{ left: animatedOffset+'px' }">
            <div class="timetable__times">
                <p class="timetable__cell p3 bg-zebra-xs">
                    1015
                </p>
                <p class="timetable__cell p3 bg-zebra bg-zebra-xs">
                    1145
                </p>
                <p class="timetable__cell p3 bg-zebra-xs">
                    1330
                </p>
                <p class="timetable__cell p3 bg-zebra">
                    1430
                </p>
                <p class="timetable__cell p3">
                    1645
                </p>
                <p class="timetable__cell p3 bg-zebra">
                    1730
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="timetable__controls col-12 hide-lg hide-md hide-sm">
        <ul class="controls">
            <li class="controls__prev"><a href="#" class="controls__link"><i class="glyphicons glyphicons-chevron-left"></i></a></li>
            <li class="controls__next"><a href="#" class="controls__link"><i class="glyphicons glyphicons-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</slider>
```

Comment: PS. I have also tried this with and without the ref="container" attribute

Comment: Can you show the code that _doesn't work_? Also, what **exactly** is the error message? Which line of code does it refer to?

Comment: The code above doesn't work e.g. :style="{ left: animatedOffset+'px' }" it doesn't get evaluated. Adding @click="prev()" to the links causes the error: InvalidCharacterError: The string contains invalid characters.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the error that when v-on:click is introduced is a symptom of the fact that the html isn't being evaluated as an inline-template (and so the v-on:click doesn't have the right scope). But - then again - I can't see why that should be so, more likely, I've missed or misunderstood something?

Comment: Not sure what to tell you but it works fine over here ~ https://jsfiddle.net/oh5p3drf/